# Cannot resolve path in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am currently using Nitrous, which shouldn't matter, but I needed to install mocha so I typed in:

```
npm install - g mocha.
```

Everything installed and when I try to run mocha in my command line I get the following error:

> /home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:454
>         if (!files.length) throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '"
>
> Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'test/unit'
>       at lookupFiles (/home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:454:32)
>       at runAgain (/home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:305:24)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object. (/home/action/.parts/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:304:6)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:902:3

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Worth noting that this error also shows up when the target directory does not have any tests in there.

Answer (score 49):

By default, mocha includes `./test/*.js`. So if that is where your tests live, just running `mocha` is all you need.

If you have your tests in `test/unit`, you might want to run `mocha ./test/unit/*.js`.

Answer (score 14):

The error you are getting is consistent with **not having a file** named `test/unit` and doing this:

```
$ mocha test/unit
```

Check that the file exists. (Actually, without a `.js` extension, I'd expect a directory rather than a *file*.) Check that you are in the right location when you issue your command.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who gets this error when trying to run:

```
> npm test
```

Make sure that your package.json file includes a test script in the format of:

`<project-root>/<custom-path-to-test>/*.js`

For example:

```
{
  "name": "Project Name",
   ...
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ./node/test/*.js"
  }
   ...
}
```

Comment: mocha assume that you are running test from "test/*.js" if you path is different then you need to provide full path, in my case it was "mocha ./projectTest/test/*.js"

Answer (score 2):

For those having mocha installed and have makefile like this:

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u tdd
.PHONY: test
```

but getting this error:

```
Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) 'test'
```

you need to add folder "test" in the project folder. And your test files in that *test* folder

```
E.G.
 /home/you/nodejs/chapter3
  ├── lib
  ├── makefile
  ├── node_modules
  ├── package.json
  └── test
       ├── db.test.js
```

Comment: I got error before adding that `test` folder. After adding the `test` folder the mocha test now run fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g mocha
npm install mocha --save-dev
```

write your test : `test.js`
add below script in your package json file

```
"scripts": {
    "api:test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 10000 --recursive test/"
},
```

go to your test directory : `npm run api:test`

https://github.com/shahing/Mocha-RestAPI-Tests

Answer (score -1):

Just move all the tests to the `test` folder, If you dont have create one.

and in the package.json file just enter 'mocha'

```js
"scripts":{
    "test": "mocha"
  },
```

and run

```
npm test
```

in the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

If you run `npm test` it will execute the `*.js` files only in test directory not in sub directories.

If you also want to execute the `*.js` test files inside sub directories of test folder.

Follow the following steps :

1. Create a mocha.opts file in test directory
2. Add following line in mocha.opts file `--recursive`