# Why can't Mocha resolve this path (or pattern)?

Tags: terminal, npm, pattern-matching, command-line-interface, mocha.js

Using windows, I keep running into NPM errors when running scripts. Is pattern matching different between OSX and Win7? Or is this mocha specific?

For example, my tests are in:

```
src/redux/normalizers/__tests__
```

and the npm script is:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive 'src/**/__tests__/*'"
```

My console (also in screenshot below) says this:

```
> mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive 'src/**/__tests__/*'

C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\redux-form\node_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js:626
    throw new Error("cannot resolve path (or pattern) '" + path + "'");
    ^

Error: cannot resolve path (or pattern) ''src/**/__tests__/*''
```

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDOuv.png

**Edit** I *was* able to change the repo author's test script for the time being to

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive src/**/__tests__/*"
```

Perhaps this is just an error on their part which nobody noticed because nobody else uses windows?

Still, I'd like to understand why. Maybe these links are useful for anyone who comes across this:

- [Cannot resolve path in Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182161/cannot-resolve-path-in-mocha)
- [Two asterisks in file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532929/two-asterisks-in-file-path)

Comment: Also here's the full npm-debug.log 
https://paste.ee/p/6Wexf

Comment: The error is thrown in [mocha's utils.js](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/63ef07f7e5cac464e0710812cdadecb009bcdf3b/lib/utils.js#L628) but it happens due to [glob's sync function](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob). I'd also like to know why does it happen

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the single quotes. I was able to run the command you provided without them. Like so:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive src/**/__tests__/*.js
```